# not able to save 2nd fragment state as it goes to new activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have 2 fragments (1,2).
after a button click on (fragment 1) transition happens to (fragment 2) .now from (fragment 2) if a button is clicked i go to the (new_activity ).my problem is when i return from (new_activity) i want to go back to (fragment 2) & then to (fragment 1) but it directly goes to fragment 1 .i am not able to add (fragment 2) to the addTOBackStack.

```
// method to handle click event of category
public void onClick(View v) {

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity()
            .getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    int categoryId;
    CategoryFragment a = new CategoryFragment();

    Log.d("HomeFragment", v.getId() + "");

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.image_american_chiffon:
        categoryId = 1;
        bundle.putInt("categoryId", categoryId);

        a.setArguments(bundle);
        ft.replace(R.id.contentFrame, a);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);

        break;
    case R.id.image_nagma:
        categoryId = 2;
        bundle.putInt("categoryId", categoryId);

        a.setArguments(bundle);
        ft.replace(R.id.contentFrame, a);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        break;

    }
    ft.commit();
    Log.e("BACK STACK COUNT",fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount()+"");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you call replace method,new object of that fragment is being created.You can add all needed fragments at the beginning in the hidden state and then just show and hide according to your need.so you don't need to initialize everytime,just have to display the required fragment and hide the other fragment.

To Add fragment at the begining,do like this:

```
Fragment myFragment = new CategoryFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, myFragment, SOME_TAG);
    transaction.hide(myFragment);
    transaction.commit();
```

and Instead of calling replace() method,just hide and show the desired fragment

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.show(getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragmentTagToBeShown));
    transaction.hide(getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(currentFragmentTag));
    transaction.commit();
```